# dotnet list package fails with error: Imported project "...\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" not found

Tags: .net

We have a VSTO-based addin and we want to monitor the NuGet packages for security vulnerabilities.

When executing the command dotnet list package --vulnerable, we receive the error below:

error: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

We can certainly write a script that temporarily removes that import and executes the scanning.

We've also tried to trick the tool - we've copied the .targets file to the instructed folder, but this didn't work.

Is there, maybe, already a solution in the existing toolchain?

Comment: Is it possible that the file "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" to be locked by other processes?

Comment: @D A: I don't think so, we can open the file in edit mode using Notepad, for example.